# Ext: how can I use data from an ajax request to modify an existing Javascript element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

For days now I've been searching for an explanation on how to do this right. I tried to find a decent tutorial for either JS or Ajax, but all the one's I found were rather basic and didn't go deep enough. When I want to solve a problem with Python, I go to Python.org, for PHP I use php.net, but I haven't found a decent ressource for JS and Ajax yet. Any tips are appreciated.

So I'll try to explain what I did. I have a rather simple page, it has a div on the left and a div on the right. Within the left one, a tree is rendered, representing a registry, within the right one, values are displayed and edited.

The tree is stored in a global variable. I have read all the warnings about using global variables, but I think it's justified in this case. Whenever this page is accessed, the tree is displayed.

```
var tree;
...
function initTree(treeRootConfig) {
    return new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
         renderTo   : 'tree'
        ,width      : 500
        ,height     : 498
        ,autoScroll : true
        ,resizable  : true

        ,useArrows  : false
        ,animate    : true
        ,loader     : {
            dataUrl  : urls.urlLoadTree,
            listeners: { beforeload : function(treeLoader, node) {} }
            },listeners: {
                 click       : function(node, e) { valueGrid.load(node.id); }
                ,contextmenu : function(node, e) {
                    cmPath.node = node;
                    cmPath.showAt(e.getXY());
            }, 
        },root     : treeRootConfig
    });
}
```

There is a textfield which holds a textual represantation of the path, that the tree is displaying.

```
function initTextfieldPath() {
    return new Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldClass     : 'textfieldPath', 
        applyTo        : 'path',
        enableKeyEvents: 'true',
        listeners      : { change : function() { refreshTree(); } },
    });
}
```

Every node is a "folder" in the path. Now when a new node is accessed, the value of the textfield is modified accordingly. This is working fine. When a new path is entered into the textfield, I want the tree to be reloaded to show the nodes. The path is parsed and and then I use Ajax to get the nodes out of the database. This works to the point, that I get the string represantation of the node, encode via JSON and try to set the node as new root for the tree.

```
function refreshTree() {    
    Ext.Ajax.request({
         url    : urls.DirectAccess
        ,scope  : tree
        ,params : { path: textfieldPath.getValue() }
        ,success: function(response, opts) {
            alert(response.responseText);
            tree.setRootNode(Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText)); }
        ,failure: function(response, opts) { noConnection(response); }
    });
}
```

As you can imagine, the alert is only in there for testing purposes. When the server request is done, it displays the string represantation of the node that was fetched from the database. Just setting this node to the tree is something I cannot get done.

The ext license that we have is for Ext 3.4.0.

Comment: How about this? It seems like it might be the same cause of your issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571358/how-to-reload-ext-tree-treepanel-on-demand

Comment: Thank you Chris, turns out it was something else altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was something else entirely. I thought it was not possible to communicate with a variable declared outside of an Ajax statement from within the Ajax statement. Turns out I had a '[' and a ']' too much. My target was expecting something like this '' but I gave it an array with only one member '[]'. It is kinda weird though, because in other cases Ext will only accept nodes as an array, no matter how many there are.